# How can I change this edit to get it passed the peer review process?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I am trying to make an Edit on Stack Overflow and cannot get it approved. But I feel like it's a valid edit. What can I do?

Here is the existing answer from *[Git push: username, password, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid/28562679#28562679)*:

---

---

Run following command to enable credential caching.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push https://github.com/repo.git

Username for 'https://github.com': <USERNAME>
Password for 'https://USERNAME@github.com': <PASSWORD>
```

Use should also specify caching expire,

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

After enabling credential caching, it will be cached for 7200 seconds (2 hour).

---

---

This author has pointed at some nice choices for dealing with OPs issue. Unfortunately due simply to saying "**also**" instead "**or**" for usage of these choices, this Answer becomes essentially *wrong*.

In removing use of the word "also", I took some extra time to elaborate more clearly the differences between these two in [Edit 17284198](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17284198), with the simple explanation of "Clarify use of `cache` instead of `store` for more security."

17284198 was rejected as "should be comment or answer". On reflection I realized I had displayed a clear bias to using `cache`, which was not the author's first suggestion, so it looked a lot like I was disagreeing with the author more-so than fixing his work.

---

---

So I edited my edit to make extra sure I treated both commands as equally valuable options. and resubmitted it as [Edit 17290715](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17290715), with a longer explanation for why this needed more than just a comment.

> Author states to use `cache` and to use `store`. Sloppy wording conflates fact that these are separate approaches to same goal. Readers are led to believe they should use both commands, so will both store credentials in plain text files and keep them in memory. This clarifies differences of each.

Here is the resulting answer:

---

---

One reasonable option is the following command to enable credential storage on your repo.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
```

This saves your password permanently in a plain text file on disk, which may be unsafe in some environments. Caching instead of storing can add some security, since the credentials never touch the disk and expire after a set time.

This command sets a cache to expire after 7200 seconds (or 2 hours).

```
$ git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

Alternatively, you may set cache or store configs globally to use with all repos.

```
$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

After setting any one of the above appropriately, your credentials will be saved for future use the next time you enter them.

```
$ git push https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git

Username for 'https://github.com': <enter USERNAME>
Password for 'https://<USERNAME>@github.com': <enter PASSWORD>

$ git push https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git

Everything up-to-date
```

---

---

This time I was rejected as "deviates from original intent". I really don't see how I am deviating, other than correcting the glaring error. I am correcting a small, but very important mistake in the text, while improving the layout and adding a small bit of extra detail for reader comprehension.

This answer is highly upvoted, and for good reason. It offers a simple solution with the result users are looking for.

However, I truly believe that in its current state, **this post is hurting the users who read it**.

It leads them astray, by convincing them to run both commands when they should only use one or the other. So they will save their passwords openly in a plain-text file and also set a cache, all-the-while mistakenly believing the cache system will expire their plain-text file, which it will not. The cache is in-memory and never goes to disk. The cache has no knowledge of the stored file.

I don't care about the reputation points. If someone with more reputation points wants to make this edit or a similar edit for me, that would definitely be OK with me. I just want to fix this post, so it does not continue doing harm to readers.

But I also would like to know what I can do differently in regards to edits to get past the review process. At this point, I feel like reviewers are trying to tell me that typo fixes are the only edits allowed.

Comment: You might wish to post this on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), the dedicated meta site for Stack Overflow, since this is an issue on a specific site rather than the whole network (which is what this site, Meta Stack Exchange, is for).

Comment: Thx @Aurora0001. Was not aware of the sub-meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *don't* get that edit past the peer review process.  It's *correctly* being rejected.

You should post your own answer, rather than editing someone else's answer to the question, if you want to make radical changes to the post and add your own original contributions.  If your answer is going to be derived from another's answer, cite their answer appropriately.

If you feel that the existing answer is harmful to readers (due to its inaccuracy, incompleteness, etc.) then the appropriate mechanism you have to provide that feedback is to downvote it, and optionally comment on it to explain to the author how they can improve it.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point of being able to edit other people's posts if you cannot fix a glaring error caused by answering in a sloppy manner? I don't disagree at all with the author's intent nor with the solution provided. I only disagree with the message that is actually coming across to the readers on the other side. Adding a _new_ answer seems quite unproductive because I don't have anything _new_ to add to the discussion, only a correction to what was already said in the wrong way.

Comment: @skylize Edits are there to improve the presentation of the author's content, not to change their content when you think it's wrong, or to add your own original contributions.  From  your suggested edit it's quite clear that you *do* have something *new* to add to the discussion, given that you not only provided your own original contributions, but you provided more content than even the original author did.  No, your edit was *not* in line with the intentions of the author. Seeing that edit you cannot reasonably say that they *intended* to post what you wrote and wrote something else instead.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure I quite follow. I made this edit working under the assumption the author said "Use should also specify caching expire," that he really meant "You could also specify caching expire", which while still slightly confusing is not glaringly wrong. It's clear as day that there is at least one typo in this sentence, I inferred the other. The rest of my changes were essentially layout improvements. Even the additional content is just to add clarity. Seems dumb to only correct the typos when a couple extra sentences would make the Answer significantly more informative.

Comment: @skylize If you're able to convince the reviewers that the author intended the answer to list two alternate options, rather than two parts of a single solution, and that your clarification makes *the author's original intentions* clearer to the reader, then that could be an acceptable edit.  You adding significant amounts of your own original work to the answer, is not.  If you want to add your own original contributions, post your own answer, don't edit your original work into someone else's answer.

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense to me. Do you have any suggestions on how I could fix my edit and/or my edit description to make it clear that " the author intended the answer to list two alternate options, rather than two parts of a single solution, and that your clarification makes the author's original intentions clearer to the reader" is what i am after in this edit?

Comment: @skylize Well, for starters, stick to just that, and don't add your own original contributions.  Other than that, try to write as clear of a revision note as you can to explain that you feel that it was the author's original intention.  Note that a reviewer might not agree with you (it's not exactly crystal clear to me, to be honest) so you may find it easier to comment on the post and have the author make that change.

Comment: the review process doesn't allow for back and forth like we are having now for me to try to get on the same page with the reviewers. I just get the changes and a single comment, followed by accept or reject. 

Comment: Thanks for your help @servy. I think your explanation of how you could theoretically be convinced this is a valid edit puts me in much better shape to tackle this productively. 

Comment: What is the `*` for? A footnote?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Bad italization.  Fixed.